# Confused about "UselessParent" Lint check

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lint

I have some layout file which Lint is giving me the following warning about:

> UselessParent
>
> Summary: Checks whether a parent layout can be removed.
>
> Priority: 2 / 10 Severity: Warning Category: Performance
>
> A layout with children that has no siblings, **is not a scrollview** or a
>   root layout, and does not have a background, can be removed and have
>   its children moved directly into the parent for a flatter and more
>   efficient layout hierarchy.

The part I'm confused about is in bold. My layout (before fixing this warning) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_margin_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_margin_small">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- TEXTVIEWS & EDITTEXTS HERE -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I fixed the warning like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_margin_small"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_margin_small">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TEXTVIEWS & EDITTEXTS HERE -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This makes sense to me but the bold part above in the Lint check is confusing me a bit, because I do have a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout. Should I not be fixing it like this or **is there no problem having a ScrollView as root element for a layout file** since a ScrollView inherits from FrameLayout anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem having a `ScrollView` as root element for a layout file. The lint complaint presumably was about your original root `LinearLayout`, which was not adding any value with just the `ScrollView` as a child.

Comment: I assumed as much but the "is not a scrollview" was confusing me. The whole sentence is a bit confusing (to me at least, English is not my first language) and I thought it was talking about the `ScrollView` inside the `LinearLayout`. Glad I could clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral: "I assumed as much but the "is not a scrollview" was confusing me." -- it's a generic message. AFAIK, they aren't templated based upon the specific view hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, but it looked like it was giving some possible examples where one of those just happened to fit my situation. I guess I was mistaken :)